# Database change not recognized by ADO using Delphi and SQL Server

Tags: delphi, ado

I run a small db application with 2 `TADOConnection` to my SQL Server. The first connection is just for viewing purpose using `ADOTable`, `Datasource` and `DBNavigator`.
The second connection is created at run time using the following code

```
aConnection:=TADOConnection.create(nil);

aTable:= TADOTable.create(nil);
aConnection.LoginPrompt := false;

.....
aTable.Edit;

aTable.Insert;

aTable.FieldByName(' ... ').AsInteger :=  .... ;

aTable.FieldByName(' .... ').AsString :=  ... ;

aTable.FieldByName(' .... ').AsString :=  ..... ;

aTable.Post;

aTable.active := false;

aConnection.connected :=false;

aTable.free;

aConnection.free;
```

If I insert records with this code I can't see the changed data if I press the Update Navigator button. I need to restart my application to see all my new inserted data. 
Why is the first dbconnection not recognizing the changes made my the second connection ?

Comment: very simple don't use 2 adoconnections...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, if I rember correct there was an issue in older Delphi/Adoverions with refresh not working as expected while requery did fine.

```
procedure TForm2.DBNavigator1Click(Sender: TObject; Button: TNavigateBtn);
begin
  if Button = nbRefresh then
  BEGIN
    if Assigned(TDBNavigator(Sender).DataSource) then
      if Assigned(TDBNavigator(Sender).DataSource.DataSet) then
        if TDBNavigator(Sender).DataSource.DataSet is TCustomAdoDataset then
          TADODataSet(TDBNavigator(Sender).DataSource.DataSet).Requery;
  END;
end;
```

Comment: this solution solved by problem , is this bug gone with XE3 & ADO ?

Comment: It't a ADO bug, I had this problem with D7 too.

Answer (score 3):

You have an `Edit`, followed immediately by an `Insert`. This means that your edit isn't changing anything (so there are no changes being made to see), and all your code is actually updating a newly created row. In other words, you tell the database you want to change the data using `Edit`, immediately tell it "I want to add a new row" (which means no data is changed by the `Edit`), and then modify the values in that newly added row. You should also be using a single `TADOConnection`.

```
 aTable.Edit;

 aTable.Insert;
```

Just remove the `aTable.Insert;` and you should be fine.

```
// Change a row that already exists.
aTable.Edit;
aTable.FieldByName(' ... ').AsInteger :=  .... ;
aTable.FieldByName(' .... ').AsString :=  ... ;
aTable.FieldByName(' .... ').AsString :=  ..... ;
aTable.Post;
```

Based on your comment to my answer, it appears you want to actually add a new row. In that case, just use the `Insert` without the `Edit` (inserting a new row automatically puts you in a mode to change the data; you don't need a separate `Edit` call).

```
aTable.Insert;
aTable.FieldByName(' ... ').AsInteger :=  .... ;
aTable.FieldByName(' .... ').AsString :=  ... ;
aTable.FieldByName(' .... ').AsString :=  ..... ;
aTable.Post;
```

`Edit` changes the current row, while `Insert` adds a new row at the current location (that may change after based on the index in use) and `Append` adds a new row at the end of the dataset (again, this might change based on the index in use).

Comment: if I follow your advise no new record will be inserted anymore, also first make insert and second step table to edit mode did not help

Comment: You asked about **changing** the data, not *adding a new row*. If you want to add a new row, remove the `Edit` and just use the `Insert`.

Comment: the code above is in the second form of my app. I close the form and whatever I press on the dbnavigator on the main form, the changes / new inserted records will not be displayed.  Close the app and start again ...  the records are displayed.

Comment: Please actually *read what I wrote*. Use one `TADOConnection` for both tables, so that the connection is aware that the data has changed. If you need to share data between forms, you should be using a `TDataModule` that can be used on both forms, with a **single** connection that's used by both.