# Bug with multiple TADOConnections

Tags: sql-server, delphi, ado

I already figured out a display table bug using ADO and SQL Server and different connections to one database. ( see details at [BUG #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843551/database-change-not-recognized-by-ado-using-delphi-and-sql-server) )

Another issues come while trying to delete records

The code goes like this

```
function resettable (tablename, databasename, servername) : Boolean;
var
  aADOQuery : TADOQuery;
  aADOConnection : TAdoConnection,
begin
  ///  Create ADO stuff 
  aADOQuery := TADOQuery.Create;
  aADOConnection := TAdoConnection.Create;

  ///  connect to DB & Table 
  ....
  ///

  aADOQuery.sql.add('delete * from ' + Tablename;
  aADOQuery.execsql;

  ///   free objects after use  
  ....
end;
```

This code works fine when the `ADOConnection` is alone on the database. If there has been some activity by any other ADO connection and some modification done, the code fails while the "database is not updated error message"

How to create a solution which will do an update prior to the delete record statement ???

Comment: As I said in your previous question. Save yourself all the trouble and use only one connection.

Comment: this is in my case a blocking point / NOGO issue; Following your advice I  would need to change all Database functions interface and add a TAdoconnection as additional parameter;  while working with diffrent forms, I always have to share the Tadoconnection ....

Comment: Yes that is the whole point, share the Connection so it knows about all changes. Just create a TDatamodule and share it between your forms?

Comment: Even if you have a single connection you will need to requery the dataset after aADOQuery.execsql. why do you use a second connection in the first place? to be honest I don't understand what your question is...?

Comment: in our project we use functions like procedure EmptyTable(aTablename : String) or procedure InsertRecordIntoTable( Tablename : String; aRecord : TAnyClass); Follow your advice I need to add the TAdoConnection inside every function call as a additional parameter, this I want to avoid

Comment: If a must avoid two ADOConnections at the same time this would mean If a run two instances of my software by different users, no user is informed on the changed made by the other user

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what you need to do. e.g. `EmptyTable(conn: TADOConnection; aTableName: string)`. or make it a DM method using your DM center `TADOConnection`. in any case you'll need to follow a `Requery` (or Close and Open) your `TDataSet` to reflect any changes to the DB. Does your second TADOConnection instance, get's informed by changes made from a first instance?. Interesting... If yes, show me how, and I will open a bounty for you and give you 500 rep!

Comment: @User: it seems that your application design is at fault here. If this is a multiuser environment and you need to see updates from other users (without requerying) then you need a multitier architecture where one tier handles all the database changes and it can inform the other clients about these changes...

Comment: This is not a *bug*. It's a poor design in your application, as several of us told you in your other question as well. Instead of fighting the problem over and over again (which in itself is a clear indication of poor design), take the time to fix it properly in the first place.

Comment: I know nothing of Delphi, but if I had to guess, I'd guess  you need to close your connection.